# Simple for loop .. never loops

Tags: c#, for-loop

There couldn't be a more simple code in existence, but I can't get it to work. I wrote exactly what the tutorial's point said and only changed the strings and parameters.

When I run this program, all that happens is it prints "Do something!!!" which I had it do just before the loop started, but the loop just doesn't show any sign of existence in the console window.

```
using System;

namespace OperatorsAppl{
    class Program{
        static void Main(string[] args){
            Console.WriteLine("Do something!!!");
            for (int a = 0; a > 10; a = a + 1){
                Console.WriteLine("Work! {0}", a);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Is this some kind of bug on the csharp developers part, or is my tutorial reference out of date or what?

Comment: `a > 10` and it starts with `a = 0` .... try `for (int a = 0; a < 10; a++)` ;)

Comment: Just checking out this section after several years of posting it. Normally you look back at what you say or do and realize you were wrong for it; but even after several years, the negative ratings where uncalled for, and there was nothing 'off-topic' about it. I posted a legitimate programming issue and received a legitimate answer for it.

Answer (score 3):

You need to look while `a` is **less** (`<`) than `10`. Your current code sets `a` to `0`, and then checks if it is **more** (`>`)than `10`, which will never be true in this case.

```
for (int a = 0; a < 10; a = a + 1){
    Console.WriteLine("Work! {0}", a);
}
```

Also note that you can simplify your addition to `a++` instead of `a = a + 1`

Comment: Wow, did I have that backwards. I thought the for loop would loop for "until" a is greater than ten, rather than "while." Thanks for clearing that up for me. By the way, did I say something bad? I'm afraid to ask, but I'm not sure why people don't like me for a simple question.

Answer (score 3):

You should learn to "Play Computer":

1. a is assigned the value 0
2. the expression `a > 10` is evaluated. The value is `false`, because `0 > 10` is false.
3. The loop exits

Answer (score 2):

Your loop statement starts at a=0. Right now it says if a > 10 (if a is bigger than 10) go in the loop else don't. You want it to say if a < 10 (if a is less than 10). As a side note you can use a++ instead of a = a+1.

```
for (int a = 0; a < 10; a++){
    Console.WriteLine("Work! {0}", a);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`a` is not greater than 10 at the start.